# sort number array in 1->9 order

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array

```
$array = array("1", "3", "2", "10", "21", "100", "4", "21", "1012", "10021", "215");
```

I want to sort like this

```
1
10
100
10021
1012
2
21
21
215
4
```

how can I do this?

I am very sorry if I asked simple question. I am beginner for php

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a flag saying you want to compare them as strings, not as numbers:

```
sort($array, SORT_STRING);
```

[more on flags](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.sort.php)